# NoMethodError: undefined method `yesterday' for Date:Class

Tags: ruby, date

Every answer posted on SO (yes, I checked) seems to have `require 'date'` as a solution. I've done that and my code still won't work.

```
require 'date'

yesterday = RepSched::Helpers.datestring(Date.yesterday)
```

For some reason, Ruby chokes on Date.yesterday

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `yesterday' for Date:Class
```

What am I doing wrong?

*edit*

Oh no! Now my problem is bigger than I thought. Now that I've realized that issue, I realize DateTime's behavior is different too!

Comment: `yesterday` is a method added by Rails

Comment: You sure you're running under Rails?

Comment: Oh. Sinatra. Hah, woops!

Comment: Try `require 'active_support/core_ext/date/calculations'`

Comment: Hah, sorry, it's a new project for me and I'm still learning where Rails ends and Ruby begins. I was testing in the Rails console.

Comment: @sent1nel Don't do that if you're not running under Rails :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`yesterday` is provided by Rails / Active Support. You can either require it in your non-Rails project:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/date/calculations'

Date.yesterday
#=> #<Date: 2014-09-02 ((2456903j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Or calculate it yourself:

```
require 'date'

Date.today - 1
#=> #<Date: 2014-09-02 ((2456903j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 6):

Rails can be a bit of a pain because it adds new methods to `Date` which surprises many newcomers to Ruby.  You can get `yesterday`, without using Rails by doing:

```
$ pry
[1] pry(main)> require 'date'
=> false
[2] pry(main)> Date.today
=> #<Date: 2014-09-03 ((2456904j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
[4] pry(main)> Date.today - 1
=> #<Date: 2014-09-02 ((2456903j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: I've chosen this answer because it better describes my problem.